# Where do I get the AzureWebJobsDashboard connection string information?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

Trying to update my Service Bus apps to use the new RTM and I need this information.

```
<add name="AzureWebJobsDashboard" connectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=;AccountKey=" />
    <add name="AzureWebJobsStorage" connectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=;AccountKey=" />
```

Previously I just used the connection string associated with each queue.  I have tried about every combination of username and key I have associated with my account with no luck.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

The AzureWebJobsDashboard connection string is your Azure Storage Account used by the Azure SDK to store logs used by the WebJobs dashboard.

The AzureWebJobsStorage connection string is your Azure Storage Account that is used to by the SDK to do things like trigger when a file is uploaded to blob storage or a message is added to a queue.  It sounds like you may not need this though if you are only using Service Bus Queues.  If this is the case for you, then you could use the same connection string that you use for the AzureWebJobsDashboard.  Generally, you would use two different storage accounts so that one is used for dashboard logging and the other is used for application functionality (queues, tables, blobs).

The connection string is available in the Azure Management Portal ([classic](https://manage.windowsazure.com/)) by click on **Storage** in the left navigation, highlight the storage account you want to use, and then click the **Manage Access Keys** button at the bottom of the page.

Comment: I'm not sure why JobHost only takes these connecting strings via config values.  I think it should also accept these as either constructor parameters.  Now I can't leverage KeyVault to obtain the connection string, or aspects of the connection string that I could then reconstitute into a connection string.  I can't have potentially sensitive logs going into a storage location whose connection information is in plain sight on the server.

Comment: hah, nm... I found JobHostConfiguration.  Somehow I overlooked that when I was looking at JobHost's constructor earlier.

Comment: Is official documentation available about this? Anybody please post a link.

Comment: Here's some documentation on the connection string: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-configure-connection-string

Answer (score 12):

The connectionString for **AzureWebJobsDashboard** and **AzureWebJobsStorage** are obtained from Azure Storage account.So follow the steps below to view the storage access keys.
1. Sign in to the Azure portal.  https://portal.azure.com
2. In the navigation pane, click on Storage accounts.
3. Choose the desired storage account,click on Access keys and copy the Connection string.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers are correct, but I add this answer to give some clarity about the `AzureWebJobsStorage` key for someone learning Azure.

When creating a function app, a storage account is also setup. And inside the Function App, a application setting named `AzureWebJobsStorage` is created.

The connection string can be seen when checking `Configuration` under Function App. This reveals the name of the name of storage account and the access key.

[image: Function App Configuration]

Under `Access keys` in the Storage Account the connection string can be confirmed to be the same.

[image: Storage Account Access keys]