# Do I need an Azure Storage Account to run a WebJob?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

So I'm fairly new to working with Azure and there are some things I can't quite wrap my head around. One of them being the Azure Storage Account.

My web jobs keeps stopping with the following error "Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: The account credentials for '*[account_name]*' are incorrect." Understanding the error however is not the problem, at least that's what I think. The problem lies in understanding why I need an Azure Storage Account to overcome it.

Please read on as I try to take you through the steps taken thus far. Hopefuly the real question will become more clear to you.

In my efforts to deploy a WebJob on Azure we have created the following resources so far:

- App Service Plan
- App Service
- SQL server
- SQL database

I'm using the following code snippet to prevent my web job from exiting:

```
JobHostConfiguration config = new JobHostConfiguration();
config.DashboardConnectionString = null;
new JobHost(config).RunAndBlock();
```

To my understanding from other sources the Dashboard connection string is optional but the AzureWebJobsStorage connection string is required.

I tried setting the required connection string in portal using the configuration found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-configure-connection-string).

```
DefaultEndpointsProtocol=[http|https];AccountName=myAccountName;AccountKey=myAccountKey
```

Looking further I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27580264/where-do-i-get-the-azurewebjobsdashboard-connection-string-information) that clearly states where I would get the values needed, namely an/my missing Azure Storage Account.

So now for the actualy question: Why do I need an Azure Storage Account when I seemingly have all the resources I need place for the WebJob to run? What does it do? Is it a billing thing, cause I thought we had that defined in the App Service Plan. I've tried reading up on Azure Storage Accounts over [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-create-storage-account) but I need a bit more help understanding how it relates to everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs:

An Azure storage account provides resources for storing queue and blob data in the cloud.

**It's also used by the WebJobs SDK to store logging data for the dashboard.**

[Refer to the getting started guide and documentation for further information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-get-started)

Comment: The docs you linked still mention making an Azure storage account. If it's true that I don't have to create one it doesn't help me understand how to achieve this.

Comment: You don't need one, no. Is it good practice to monitor your log files, yes. So it is not mandatory, but it is recommended.

Comment: Here Im not using any dashboard logging or any logging connected to Azure storage. When I was using v1.x of this webjobs sdk, even storage string is mandatory, nothing was written into the azure storage. But when I used v.2.x of this sdk, it creates a blob container called azure-webjobs-hosts and write some data. Why azure is having this info in this blob?

Comment: Seems like webjobs is taking a dependency on storage. I know durable functions now relies on storage to maintain state. I haven't had chance to look at what functions 2.x is storing in the blob.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is "No", it is not mandatory to use Azure Storage when you are trying to setup and run a Azure web job.

If you are using `JobHost` or `JobHostConfiguration` then there is indeed a dependency for Storage accounts.

Sample code snippet is give below.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Functions.ExecuteTask();
    }

}

public class Functions
{
    [NoAutomaticTrigger]
    public static void ExecuteTask()
    {
        // Execute your task here 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, you don't. You can have a WebJob run without being tied to an Azure Storage Account. Like Murray mentioned, your WebJob dashboard does use a storage account to log data but that's completely independent.

Comment: I'm assuming I would have to remove the code snippet I posted from my code to have it not log data. My next problem would be how to keep my program from exiting cause that's what I'm using JobHost(config).RunAndBlock(); for?

Comment: You don't need the JobHost either. A WebJob can be a simple console application. The JobHost is part of the WebJobs SDK which you are not required to use.